# get all data from a firestore subcollection flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get all the data in a firestore subcollection.

This is how my firestore collection looks like:

[image: firestore collection]

The collection Products has a product with a field productName. I

I can display the list name by accesing the snapshot data

```
CloudShoppingListsCart.fromSnapshot(QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot, this.products)
  : shoppingListId = snapshot.id,
    name = snapshot.data()['name'] as String;
```

but is there a way to access the collection `products` and his fields like I did in `snapshot.data()`?

The method where I call `fromSnapshot` is this:

```
Stream<Iterable<CloudShoppingListsCart>> getShoppingCartListDetails({required String shoppingCartListId}){

final shoppingList = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(shoppingListCollectionName)
    .doc(shoppingCartListId).collection(shoppingListCartCollectionName).snapshots().map((event) =>
    event.docs
        .map((doc) => CloudShoppingListsCart.fromSnapshot(doc, [])));

return shoppingList;
```

I want to get the product name for displaying it in a ListTile like this

```
return ListTile(
  leading: const Icon(Icons.list),
  trailing: const Text(
     "GFG",
     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 15),),

  title: Text('List item $productsName'));
```

I am already displaying the list name in a column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FireStore queries are shallow, so the sub collection is not loaded. You have to perform another query to get the documents in `products` collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Peter commented: read operations on Firestore are shallow. A document snapshot from the parent collection, does not contain snapshots from its subcollections.

This means that you will have to execute an additional read operation to get the documents from the `products` subcollection.